# How to pass a dynamic parameter name into visualforce?

Tags: visualforce, parameters

```
<apex:repeat value="{!comp_set}" var="fieldName">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="emailaddress" class="col-sm-4 control-label">{!fieldName}</label>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <p class="p-values">
            <apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.[fieldName]}"/>
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
</apex:repeat>
```

Is there a way we can display like this in visualforce page. 
I tried it but it has an error.

> Save error: Expression of type Text cannot be subscripted.

The value of nationality__c and religion__c is what I want to display in the output.

```
USER_DEBUG|[167]|DEBUG|System.PageReference[/apex/bookingconfirmation?Email=lennon.greg.15%40gmail.com&FirstName=Lennon&id=a0X9000000AlE7hEAF&LastName=Pasco&nationality__c=Filipino&religion__c=Christian]
    14:31:15.443 (443045689)|SYSTEM_METHOD_EXIT|[167]|System.debug(ANY)
```

But when I used this `<apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters.religion__c}"/>`

It display this:

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you passed the correct parameter in the URL... can you post the URL you are trying to hit and full code of the output text

Comment: I updated the post sir.

Comment: Check for `.` when you accessing map values, trye `<apex:outputText value="{!$CurrentPage.parameters[fieldName]}"/>`

Comment: I tried it already. But still the same error.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a controller? Then you could grab all of the page parameters in the controller local map and try to access them as a controller property. One more thought your field name value is Religion but the parameter is religion__c right?

Comment: And parameter[something] must be used without a dot.